# Can a linear map of polynomials be defined without using the maximum degree of the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I cam across this question, but am confused how to write this linear map as a matrix transformation:

> Consider T ∈ L(P2(R),P2(R)) defined by a + bx → (a + 2b) + (−a − 2b)x.
>
> (1) Find out det(T) and Tr (T).
>
> (2) Find out Null T, Range T and Rank (T). Is Null T + Range T a direct sum? Is Null T +
>   Range T equal to P2(R)?
>
> (3) Find out the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of T. Is det(T) equal to the product of
>   eigenvalues? Is Tr (T) equal to the sum of eigenvalues?

It looks to me like the transformation defined a polynomial of degree 1 sent to another polynomial of degree 1. Do we just send all coefficients of x^2 to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Your linear transformation is transforming polynomials. So, your basis vectors can be picked as $1$, $x$. Now, look at the effect of  $T$ on $1$ and $x$

$$
T (a + bx) = (a + 2b) + (-a -2b)x 
$$

Hence,
$$
a \to a + 2b \\
b \to -a -2b
$$

In matrix form, if I write the coefficient of $1$ in the first row and the coefficient of $x$ in the second row, then my equation becomes

$$
T\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a + 2b \\ -a -2b \end{bmatrix}
$$

This captures the effect of $T$ on any vector $(a, b)$ of the space.

Comment: Thank you - very helpful! So even though the transformation is mapping to and from polynomials of degree 2 or less, if we choose a basis that leaves out polynomials with degree 2 then we do not need to consider these?